# In "Darker than Black: Ryuusei no Gemini", what happens to Hei's powers?

Tags: darker-than-black

In the second season of *Darker than Black* (*Darker than Black: Ryuusei no Gemini*), Hei mysteriously...

> ...loses his contractor powers somewhere in the middle of the season.

In the beginning of the anime we can clearly see that...

> ...Hei still has his contractor powers, since he uses them in a fight in episode 2.

However, in later episodes it is revealed by some of the characters that...

> ...Hei's powers are completely lost, and he is but an ordinary human (well, a well-trained human, at least).

So what was the reason for...

> ...Hei losing all of his contractor power out of sudden, and without being noticed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you notice that at the beginning of "Gemini of the Meteor" season BK-201's star vanishes, and he loses his powers. At the end of the season,

> BK-201's star lighting up in the sky.

Each "False Star" has a corresponding Contractor, and they resonate when their Contractor's power is being used. As such I think it's safe to conclude the he has his powers back.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111015120036AAoyI2T), Hei lost his powers because of the trap that ensnared Hei in episode two. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Darker_than_Black_episodes):

> Hei and Suō are caught in a trap after Hei seemingly kills August 7 by electrocuting the British Contractor. Later on, Misaki Kirihara is shown looking through a telescope which is directed towards the star of BK-201. The star fades away.

Comment: Suou was wearing the meteor fragment; Hei's powers _(which was actually Bai fused with him)_ got transferred into it.  I thought they made that pretty clear in the anime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he will regain his powers. It's possible.

In the Hell's Gate you can find what you lost, so he can get his powers back.

Answer (score 0):

I think BK-201's star in the end of 2nd season means someone with Hei's power  appeared. I think a new Contractor which is Hei's copies appeared. In the end, there is a new syndicate, a new Yin, new Contractors... why not a new Hei?